# Экпорт await выражения esm

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, модули, export

Пробую выполнить следующий код в окружении Node.js используя esm либу https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

export const con = await createConnection({
    type: "sqlite",
    database: "db.sqlite",
    entities: ['./user.js'],
    synchronize: true,
});

export {}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
export const con = await createConnection({
                   ^
SyntaxError: ]
```

Comment: никогда не видел *esm* в глаза, но Вы уверенны, что можно использовать `await`  вне `async` функции? Вы же не *Deno* используете

Comment: Уверен. ESM это допускает. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

Comment: @CatGrey допускает, но это не значит что их можно экспортировать. И не значит, что они внезапно заработают в ноде

Answer (score 0):

[Async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) работает только в контексте асинхронной функции, вот так:

```js
async function doSomething() {
  await createConnection( ... );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

и всё таки попробуйте так:

```
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

export const con = (async () => await createConnection({
    type: "sqlite",
    database: "db.sqlite",
    entities: ['./user.js'],
    synchronize: true,
}))();

export {};
```

Comment: Я думаю в этом нет смысла, потому что в con будет записан promise. Это равносильно export const con = createConnection({ ...

Comment: Просто неудобно дальше в проекте работать с promise. Думаю логичнее было бы при запуске инициализировать соединение с бд и дальше использовать чистый объект соединения